# GLAD link is not providing needed functions

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glfw, glad

TLDR: The GLAD header file won't let me use the openGL Commands and I don't know exactly why.

Here's a breakdown:

- I'm on a Windows 10 Laptop.
- I'm coding in C++.
- I'm compiling with MinGW's g++ tool.
- I'm using GLFW and GLAD.
- My file layout is something like this:

  ```
  OpenGLTest
      include
          glad
              glad.h
          GLFW
              glfw3.h
              glfw3native.h
          KHR
              khrplatform.h
      glad.c
      glfw3.dll
      GraphicsTest.cpp(Main File)
      libglfw3dll.a(I have forgotten what this does, it's a remnant from older attempts at openGL. Relevant?)
      Makefile(a single command: "g++ GraphicsTest.cpp -g -L glad.c glfw3.dll")
  ```
- As far as I can tell, the program will compile and run flawlessly if any and all commands from GLAD and openGL are commented out. All it then does is make a small window.
- If said lines are not commented out, the compiler will throw a slew of errors, all following this form:

  ```
  D:\Documents\Programming\C++\Programs\OpenGLTest/GraphicsTest.cpp:23: undefined reference to `gladLoadGL'
  ```

  ...with gladLoadGL being replaced with the relevant function.
- The file itself reads thusly:

  ```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<glad\glad.h>
  #include<GLFW\glfw3.h>

  static void whatIsGoingOnSeriouslyGuysHelp(int id,const char* desc)
  {
      std::cout<<desc;
  }
  int main()
  {
      glfwSetErrorCallback(&whatIsGoingOnSeriouslyGuysHelp);
      glfwInit();
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
      glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

      GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(100,100,"TEST",NULL,NULL);
      if (window == NULL)
      {
          std::cout<<"Window Creation Error";
      }
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
      gladLoadGL();
      //glViewport(0,0,100,100);

      while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
      {
          //std::cout<<"?";
          glfwPollEvents();
          glfwSwapBuffers(window);
          //glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
          //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      }
      glfwDestroyWindow(window);
      glfwTerminate();
      return 0;
  }
  ```

I have tried re-installing GLAD, but that didn't do anything. I haven't tried re-installing GLFW, but I don't *think* that's the problem.

Correct any misconceptions I have or errors I am making.

Comment: why didn't use a modern build system , like CMake?

Comment: What GLAD generator parameters were used?  Check the comment block at the top of `glad.h` under `Commandline:` and `Online:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `glad.c` in your compile command as follows: (you had a `-L` before it which tells gcc to treat glad.c as a directory for libraries)

```
g++ GraphicsTest.cpp glad.c -g glfw3.dll
```

, and instead of `gladLoadGL`, you should use the GLFW loader:

```
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize OpenGL context" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
```

Finally, you should invest a tiny bit of time into a decent build system because compiling every file every time will get real slow real fast. Here is the absolute minimal Makefile to get you started:

```
graphicstest: graphicstest.o glad.o
  g++ -g -o $@ $^ glfw3.dll
```

Comment: Thanks! The first bit solved the problem and I'll be sure to implement the second. About the third, though...I don't fully understand. I am using a makefile, as mentioned, but is the method you were showing a better one than mine? How so? Where should I go to learn more about this topic?

Comment: My makefile compiles each c file independently, and only if the file has changed. Yours will compile glad.c from scratch every time. And it gets worse the more files you add.